# android studio dump debug variables

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a plugin for Android Studio that allows me to dump all variables that are able to be resolved by the debugger, at a breakpoint?

I.e. I have a class with say 20 members in it, and they all have members, etc etc..instead of having to click down through the hierarchy, I would like to just dump those to a text file or xml or something.

Separately - I would also be interested in knowing if there was a recursive string-search feature for all variables visible at a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you mentioned cannot be achieved as of now, but you can give [JVM Debugger Memory View](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8537-jvm-debugger-memory-view) a try.

Comment: i saw that before, but the problem is if you have many instances of a class or data type, it can still be a ton of data to try to sift through